# HTTP iframe over HTTPS Connection on Server?

Tags: https

I have read about the inverse of SF.  To start I know this is **bad and less than optimal.**  But here is the situation.  I assume my thinking on this is flawed and wanted to know if I am right or wrong here.

I have users authenticating to a webapp that is controlled by the shared hosting provider.  It is not secured; it comes over plain HTTP on 80.  I do have control to my own secure services on 443 with a proper cert on my domain.  I created a subdirectory (it is not a wildcard cert), that is just a full page iframe that goes to the auth page of that shared hosting service.  My *rationale for loading a HTTP frame over a HTTPS connection is that is loaded securely through the tunnel and runs around my server on their internal network instead of public internet.*  In theory that is not as bad.  Is that even a remotely safe assumption?

This is not a permanent thing, but I need some kludge in place until I can shift gears and get rid of this.

Answer (score 1):

The contents of `IFRAME` elements are not served by the same server (i.e. it's not a proxy). The browser will go directly to the location specified for the `IFRAME` to load the content. You are not securing the subpage in any way by loading it inside an `IFRAME` on an HTTPS page.

Answer (score 1):

Modern browsers such as Google Chrome and Mozilla Firefox complain about something called "mixed content", which is basically when a website is served partially in HTTPS, so you're gonna have a bad time executing what you're proposing.

Instead, on your own server, create a location and serve that content through a reverse proxy. It is more secure to your users and you'll provide them a better experience.

Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure if get get what your doing but I guess how it works will depend on the client browser and how it reacts to having unsecured pages on a secured page.

Different browsers react differently.

Comment: I am more interested in where the traffic goes, but point taken.